# MySQL DB Error 1064 when trying to restore backup

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I know there are several questions on here about MySQL DB error #1064 (syntax error) but I haven't found one that matches what I'm asking.

I created a backup of the MySQL database for an organization's WordPress site that I've been working on. They recently had a security breach and I wanted to change the default table prefix (wp_) to something a lot less obvious. I started running into issues and decided to start clean by restoring from the back up.

Unfortunately, whenever I try to import the backup into the same database without having edited it at all I'm getting the 1064 syntax error. On top of that, the error says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 115" but there is not ? anywhere near line 115 so I don't even know where to begin looking for the error.

I'm completely at a loss as to how that could be. I'd greatly appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your sql codes?